# Does [NSData getBytes: length:] change position in buffer?

Tags: objective-c, buffer, nsdata

I have some NSData instance with 2 bytes of different value.

Will calling getBytes: of any kind (length, range...) also advance the current position in the buffer?

Example:

```
NSData *data = ...; // 2 bytes data
[data getBytes:&whatever1 length:1]; // reading first byte
[data getBytes:&whatever2 length:1]; // reading first OR second byte?
```

Will the contents that I get on each time getBytes:length: is called be the same first byte in the NSData instance or will the first call advance the next call to read from the second byte?

Thanks!

Comment: No.  NSData is immutable, so no (legitimate) operation on it would change its contents.  (There are ways to modify the contents, but they would be using "unsafe" access in violation of the spec.)

Comment: The `length` parameter is the "number of bytes from the start of the receiver's data to copy to buffer." So, if you use `length` of `1`, it's always the first byte. Use `getBytes:range:`, adjusting the `location` of the `range` if you want to iterate through the bytes of the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it does not.

In the example it will access the same byte (first).

To access the "next" byte you'll need to use getBytes:range: but, like @hot-licks commented, NSData is immutable and therefore won't be modified.